# How to debug already built app on iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I developed an iOS app using Xcode and I installed it on my iPhone. It's running very well. No bugs, no crash until today. When I launch the app it crashes and I can't start it.

If something like this happened, could the bug be in the AppDelegate.Swift?

The question is how can I debug the app copy that is on my iPhone because if I launch it by Xcode to debug it, it will reinstall it and the bug will be gone.

Comment: Save your logs.

Comment: How long ago did you last install the app via Xcode? Are you using a paid developer account?

Comment: @rmaddy weeks ago last time , no I'm not using paid dev account

Comment: It happened to me a month ago, because I changed the country and my app was using the current gps coordinations of the user. Maybe if your app is using a gps, check that. Else try to delete it from you phone and launch it again, hope it helps :)